# Moved data from an ext4 volume to an ext3 volume and it is consuming more space, why?

Tags: linux, storage, ext3, ext4

Just need a simple answer, did some searching and couldn't find it.  What is the metadata overhead with ext3 as compared to ext4?  I migrated a number of volumes from a SAN that was using ext4 volumes to a new storage array that is formatted as ext3 and the volumes are anywhere from 2-3% to 11% larger.  Average increase is about 6.5% across the board.  Everything is working and all of the files are there with plenty of space to spare so not a major issue, but I thought a 6+% percent difference seems a bit high to me.

Answer (score 1):

The block size of ext3 volume is probably larger then the block size of ext4 volume.

If, e.g. the block size of ext4 was 4096 bytes and the block size of ext3 is 8192 bytes, then a small file (like 1k or so) takes 4k on ext4 volume and 8k on ext3.